# Include Null check in MongoRepository query by example

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I Am trying to find all from a collection that match certain search criteria using MongoRepository using the following method:

```
<S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
```

To do this I am building an ExampleMatcher for all fields that are included in the search. like so:

```
 private ExampleMatcher buildMatcher(FormSearchParameters formSearchParameters) {

    ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()

            .withIgnorePaths("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4" , "f5");

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(formSearchParameters.getName())) {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withMatcher("name", match -> match.regex());
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(formSearchParameters.getFoo())) {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withMatcher("foo", matcher -> matcher.exact().ignoreCase());
    }

    if (null != formSearchParameters.getFilter()) {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withMatcher("filter", matcher -> matcher.exact());
    }
    else {
        exampleMatcher = exampleMatcher.withIgnorePaths("filter");
    }

    return exampleMatcher.withIncludeNullValues();
}
```

However I need to add a last check where a field (say nullField) is null. I cant seem to find any information on how to go about this in the documentation.

I have tried adding the following where nullField is null in the example model provided but this seems to be ignored.

```
.withMatcher("nullField", matcher -> matcher.exact())
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers) the Null-handling setting is scoped to the ExampleMatcher (not the property path). So, long story short, you can't.